# how to CHECK the version of SSL in IIS server 7?

Tags: ssl, iis-7

I have disabled SSL 2.0 in IIS server 7. How can I determine which SSL version is enabled in my web server?

Answer (score 2):

If the server is publicly accessible you could use [Qualys SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with hmallett if the website is public. I have also used the openssl command on Linux to test as well. [This](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/test-ssl-certificates-diagnosis-ssl-certificate/) link gives a lot of detail regarding how to use it. There has also been a previous question regarding the same topic that can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/106482/how-can-i-see-what-version-of-ssl-a-web-server-is-currently-using).